# Polymer 0.5 equivalent form element

Tags: html, polymer

What is the element in polymer 0.5 which is equivalent to "form" element in html. Can see there is an "iron-form" element in higher versions of polymer but couldn't find an element in 0.5.

Please share details on element or any other way to implement "form" element in polymer 0.5

I am trying to submit something like below using polymer 0.5

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```

Comment: polymer 0.5 is really old and there were different elements than now (they had prefix `core-`) so maybe here you can find something. But I think that find something for 0.5 will be difficult

Answer (score 0):

After performing below changes, it worked.

```
<form name="logoutForm" id="logoutId" action="/j_spring_security_logout" method='POST'>
        <core-icon-button icon="lock" on-click="{{ logout }}" ></core-icon-button>
    </form>
```

and in the script added below,

```
logout: function () {
          var form = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('logoutId');
          form.submit();     
      }
```